# Unexpected memcpy on uncopyable & unmovable type when using co_await

Tags: c++, undefined-behavior, copy-elision, c++-coroutine

#### Preamble

This is a description of what I am trying to do with the code, skip to the next section to see the actual issue.

I want to use coroutines in an embedded system, where I can't afford too many dynamic allocations. Therefore, I am trying the following: I have non-copyable, non-movable awaitable types for the various queries to peripherals. When querying a peripheral, I use something like `auto result = co_await Awaitable{params}`. The constructor of the awaitable prepares the request to the peripheral, registers its internal `buffer` to receive the reply, and registers its `ready` flag in the promise. The coroutine is then suspended.

Later, the `buffer` will be filled, and the `ready` flag will be set to `true`. After this, the coroutine knows that it can be resumed, which the causes the awaitable to copy out the result from the buffer before being destroyed.

The awaitable is non-copyable and non-movable to force guaranteed copy elision everywhere, so that I can be sure that the pointers to `buffer` and `ready` remain valid until the awaitable has been awaited (at least that was the plan...)

#### The issue

I am encountering an issue with ARM GCC 11.3 in the following code:

```cpp
#include <cstring>
#include <coroutine>

struct AwaitableBase {
    AwaitableBase() = default;
    AwaitableBase(const AwaitableBase&) = delete;
    AwaitableBase(AwaitableBase&&) = delete;

    AwaitableBase& operator=(const AwaitableBase&) = delete;
    AwaitableBase& operator=(AwaitableBase&&) = delete;

    
    char buffer[65];
};

struct task {
    struct promise_type
        {
            bool* ready_ptr;

            task get_return_object() { return {}; }
            std::suspend_never initial_suspend() noexcept { return {}; }
            std::suspend_always final_suspend() noexcept { return {}; }
            void return_void() {}
            void unhandled_exception() {}
        };
};

struct Awaitable{
    AwaitableBase base;
    bool ready{false};

    bool await_ready() {return false;}
    void await_suspend(std::coroutine_handle<task::promise_type> handle)
    {
        handle.promise().ready_ptr = &ready;
    }
    int await_resume() { return 2; }
};

AwaitableBase make_awaitable_base()
{
    return AwaitableBase{};
}


task example()
{
    co_await Awaitable{make_awaitable_base()};
}
```

When compiling this with ARM GCC 11.3 without any optimizations, the code contains a `memcpy` call that moves around the `AwaitableBase` object (excerpt from [Godbolt](https://godbolt.org/z/xWcM8YY4P)):

```
ldr     r3, [r7, #4]
adds    r3, r3, #87
mov     r0, r3
bl      make_awaitable_base()
ldr     r2, [r7, #4]
ldr     r3, [r7, #4]
add     r0, r2, #21
adds    r3, r3, #87
movs    r2, #65
mov     r1, r3
bl      memcpy
ldr     r3, [r7, #4]
movs    r2, #0
strb    r2, [r3, #86]
ldr     r3, [r7, #4]
adds    r3, r3, #21
mov     r0, r3
bl      Awaitable::await_ready()
```

This breaks my code, as I am relying the fact that the object cannot be moved/copied. It was my understanding that making an object non-copyable & non-movable should prevent it from being memcopied.

#### Observations/Comments

- The `memcpy` is no longer present in 13.1 - unfortunately, I am stuck with 11.3
- The `memcpy` is not present if I remove the aggreate initialization of `Awaitable` wrapped around `AwaitableBase` (and instead make `AwaitableBase` itself the awaitable) - this doesn't work for me because I'd like to wrap other awaitables with `Awaitable` to modify their behavior
- The `memcpy` is not present without the `co_await`
- As noted previously, I need the awaitable to have a stable address, as I rely on the fact that I can look at the `ready_ptr` stored in the promise to check if the awaitable is done.

#### Question(s)

How can I work around this?
Is it a bug with the compiler, or am I misunderstanding something about guaranteed copy elision? Is it undefined behavior to rely on the fact that the address of the temporary should not change during the duration of the `co_await` call?

Comment: Looks like [this bug](https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=101976) and there are several other similar ones like [this](https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=102217) (but don't quote me on this).

Comment: @n.m. Thanks! That does seem to be it, apparently my bug-searching skills need some improvement. I guess in that case I either have to hope for some clever workaround, or rework the entire thing...

Comment: Looks like the bug is with creating a temporary directly in the `co_await` expression. If you hoist it out like `co_await []{ return Awaitable{make_awaitable_base()}; }();` it doesn't seem to `memcpy` anymore. Does that work around work in your code base?

Comment: Additional function with the body `return Awaitable{make_awaitable_base()};` can eliminate `memcpy` call: https://godbolt.org/z/6hqxj8foP Can you use it as a workaround?

Comment: @Artyer Thanks! That does indeed work for my case. If you post it as an answer, I'll be very happy to accept it

Comment: @Fedor Thanks for the suggestion. That also works as far as I can tell, unfortunately it's a bit harder to apply that the lambda suggested by Artyer in my case. Nevertheless, it's a nice alternative to keep in mind

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As pointed out in the comments, this is a [GCC bug](https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=101976), where prvalues created by constructing objects in `co_await` expressions are erroneously treated as trivially copyable aggregates, creating a temporary that is `memcpy`'d from.

The fix is to never construct a non-trivial object directly in a `co_await` expression. E.g., `co_await Class{ ... }`, `co_await function_call(Class{ ... })` and `co_await Class{ ... }.member_function()` are all prone to this bug.

You can replace these with `co_await [&]{ return ...; }();` (which is `co_await lambda_type(captured_references...)()`, where that lambda type can be memcpy copied)

You might want to macro-ify this to `#define CO_AWAIT(...) co_await [&]() -> decltype(auto) { return __VA_ARGS__ ; }()` so you can just search for lowercase `co_await` in your code base to completely eliminate this bug.